# Dilema Laravel 5.5 ORM y Base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-5

Tengo una consulta con respecto a la lógica que debería utilizar para utilizar en producción en un sistema inmobiliario:

En un formulario cargo (itero) los ambientes:

```
// ... formulario
@forelse(App\Ambiente::all() as $env)
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="env_{{ $env->id }}" class="control-label">
            {{ $env->name }}
        </label>
        @switch($env->type)
            @case('int')
                <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" id="env_{{ $env->id }}" name="env_{{ $env->id }}" placeholder="{{ $env->placeholder }}" @if(old('env_{{ $env->id }}')) value="{{ old('env_' . $env->id) }}" @elseif(isset($property)) @endif>
                @break
            @case('tf')
                <label class="switch switch-sm">
                    <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="env_{{ $env->id }}" name="env_{{ $env->id }}" @if(old('env_{{ $env->id }}')) value="{{ old('env_' . $env->id) }}" @endif>
                    <span class="slider"></span>
                </label>
                @break
            @default

        @endswitch
    </fieldset>
@empty
    <p>No hay ambientes disponibles. <a href="{{ action('EnvironmentController@create') }}"> Agregar</a></p>
@endforelse
// formulario ...
```

Éste es el modelo `Ambiente` que tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: Información tabla]

Y luego donde mi ignorancia entra en acción, es el formulario `Propiedad` que es el que ingresa toda la información.

**Opción 1:** Agrego una columna de tipo string `ambientes` que ingresa cada ambiente separado por coma en la misma propiedad.

**Opción 2:** Agrego otro modelo llamado `ValoresAmbiente` que tenga una estructura por ejemplo *propiedad_id* (clave foránea a la tabla **propiedades**) y *ambiente_id* (clave foránea a **ambientes**) que se añada a BD cuando se crea una **App\Propiedad**:

[image: Tabla 2]

¿Qué sugirirían? ¿Otra opción? Agradezco cualquier comentario y disculpen la ignorancia.

Comment: Para mi lo mejor seria la Opción 2 asi mantienes una mejor estructura de tu BD con su entidad referencial.

Comment: Es una relación [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), crearías la tabla `ambiente_propiedad` y `propiedades`. Con los modelos `Ambiente` y `Propiedad` es suficiente, no tenés que crear uno para la tabla pivot.

Comment: @azeós, sería como la opción 2 pero sin modelo, ¿no es verdad?

Comment: Exacto, el modelo no es necesario porque se deduce de la relación entre los otros dos.

Comment: @azeós, entonces tendría que insertar directamente en la base de datos con `DB::table('ambiente_propiedad')->insert([ 'ambiente_id' => x, 'propiedad_id' => x ]);`

Comment: @Maramal No, si estás usando `Eloquent` tenés los métodos [attach y detach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships). Estoy desde un celular y se me complica darte una respuesta completa. Pero revisá los dos links que te pasé.